I try to transfere my SOl from account but get (os error 2)
I try to transfer SOl by using this command solana transfer --from <KEYPAIR> <RECIPIENT_ACCOUNT_ADDRESS> <AMOUNT> --fee-payer <KEYPAIR> from account to my wallet but I get  errors error: Invalid value for '--from <FROM_ADDRESS>': The system cannot find the file specified. (os error 2) and with error: Invalid value for '--fee-payer <KEYPAIR>': The system cannot find the file specified. (os error 2)
I try solana config set --keypair with path to my keypair.json but it doesn't help

It seems that the paths you are providing the command are wrong.
Check that your local paper wallet exists in the  ~/.config/solana directory. From your question, it seems that you'd like to use keypair.json as your default signer(it usually defaults to id.json)
If the keypair file keypair.json does not exist
solana-keygen new -o ~/.config/solana/keypair.json

Set this as the default signer
solana config set -k ~/.config/solana/keypair.json


I know that I must have id.json but I haven't. Anyway command ask to use keypair.json and this file I have. But it doesn't work, am I do something wrong?

Have you made sure that the paths are correct?

Yeh. several times. My keypair.json looks like this DLuEogKAYPL5MiQAuBEtXJwqeM2J5w7ihsSK52ACG7Q3 .json

Where is you keypair.jsin file saved and in which directory are you working in? Try generating a new key pair and using it
